problem starting a jhipster application with a dependency on camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter
Can you help me please?
Following the generation of the jhipster application, I try to insert the dependency:
org.camunda.bpm.springboot camunda-bpm-spring-boot-starter 7.22.0 
And when it starts I get an error probably related to the spring security configuration, but unfortunately, this is beyond my skills.
Here is the stack:
2024-12-05T10:04:31.280+01:00  WARN 16334 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'filterChain' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'filterChain' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'mvc' defined in class path resource [com/mycompany/myapp/config/SecurityConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'mvc' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'mvcHandlerMappingIntrospector' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpointWebMvcHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointWebExtensionConfiguration$MvcAdditionalHealthEndpointPathsConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.servlet.AdditionalHealthEndpointPathsWebMvcHandlerMapping]: Factory method 'healthEndpointWebMvcHandlerMapping' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthEndpoint' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'healthContributorRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'healthContributorRegistry' parameter 2: Error creating bean with name 'org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringProcessEngineServicesConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'processEngine': Error creating bean with name 'processEngineFactoryBean': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation

I tried different possibilities but I think it comes from the spring security configuration and I don't know how to do it correctly.
